# Ubuntu 23.04 not starting

Tags: dual-boot, acpi, grub-efi, 23.04

Recently I installed Windows 10 after Ubuntu 23.04, and I repaired GRUB, all good. The dual boot system was working fine. Yesterday I added a new GPU and this is what I get now when I am trying to boot Ubuntu.

[image: this is]